# Include OpenCV in android application package

Tags: android, image, image-processing, opencv

I need to work on detecting edges from an Image, I'm using Canny algorithm for that.
Since OpenCV for android is available 2.4.2 while i'm trying to run examples it says.
"OpenCV Manager is not installed, please try to install it." after install it from the market it is working fine.

But if i want the user's to install my application so that they don't have to install another .apk for using my application.

-> How to use openCV without without asking for another application i.e. manger should be pre installed.?

-> is there any way i can use Canny algorithm for edge detection without OpenCV any good angorithm tutorials for implementing in in android.?

Answer (score 1):

You might find information about this on the [OpenCV webpage](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/dev_with_OCV_on_Android.html#application-development-with-static-initialization). This said, this is deprecated and OpenCV advises not to do this in production. The manager actually allows the user to download the OpenCV library once for all. Then, your application will be much smaller!

About not using OpenCV, you can try FastCV (as Aaron suggested), but it seems overkill for your application (and it requires you to be familiar with NDK development). With OpenCV, in the other hand, you can code either in java (by the way, have a look at [JavaCV](https://code.google.com/p/javacv/)) or using the NDK.

Finally, if you only need a Canny Edge detector and don't want to use a library, you can try to write it yourself. The related page on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canny_edge_detector) should be enough for this (I could do it a few years ago as an exercise).

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into Qualcomm's FastCV? It offers some of the more common image processing algorithms offered in libraries like OpenCV. They also have a pretty cool augmented reality API called Vuforia.

Fair warning, the support documentation isn't that great and it requires that you are familiar with NDK development.

https://developer.qualcomm.com/mobile-development/mobile-technologies/computer-vision-fastcv

Comment: FastCV is **not** an android version of OpenCV. It's a different library, that offers some (a few) of the functionalities of OpenCV.